# How to make for each loop stop at first true condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm making a login/sign up form as a small personal project and I've ran into a slight snag.

All new users are stored in local storage.
When users login, I want to retrieve all the users from local storage and loop through them to see if the login details match the users sign up details.

I have basically created the code, I just can't get the `if/else` statement to work correctly. It returns `true` if the value is `true`, but keeps on looping through and returns `false` for the ones that aren't `true`.

How do I get the loop to stop at the first `true` value?

Here is my code:

```
// gather information and loop through users array
document.querySelector("#login").addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
    // login details gathered from user
    var logId = document.getElementById("logId").value;
    var logPass = document.getElementById("logPass").value;
    // get all the users from local stroage and loop through
    var allUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    allUsers.forEach(function(user) {
        if (user.userId === logId && user.userPassword === logPass) {
            console.log("true");
        } else {
            console.log("fasle");
        }
    });
    // prevent form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: whats wrong with `return`?

Comment: @AyushGupta return in `forEach` work like `continue` in `for` ,  check my answer soulotion is try-catch

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend using `.some`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

This will return `true` if any of the user's match to your requirement else `false`

```
   let isUserMatched = allUsers.some(function(user) {
       return user.userId === logId && user.userPassword === logPass)
    });
   if(isUserMatched){
     // do something
   }
```

Comment: I am glad It helped you. Please accept the answer so it will be helpful for others too.

Answer (score 2):

there is no easy way to short circuit the `forEach`, what you could do is use a traditional for loop like this

```
// gather information and loop through users array
document.querySelector("#login").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // login details gathered from user
    var logId = document.getElementById("logId").value;
    var logPass = document.getElementById("logPass").value;
    // get all the users from local stroage and loop through

    var allUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    for (var i = 0; i < allUsers.length; i++) {
        if(user.userId === logId && user.userPassword === logPass){
            console.log("true");
            break;
        } else {
            console.log("false");
        }
    }
   // prevent form from submitting
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the MDN documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
>   throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method
>   is the wrong tool. Use a plain loop or for...of instead. If you are
>   testing the array elements for a predicate and need a Boolean return
>   value, you can use every() or some() instead. If available, the new
>   methods find() or findIndex() can be used for early termination upon
>   true predicates as well.

Alternatively, what you could also possibly do is

```
var currentUser = allUsers.find(function fn(user) {
  return user.userId === logId && user.userPassword === logPass;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use a normal for loop (not foreach) and use break;  to come out of the for loop when the condition is true

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` isn't really a statement. It's just a `function` that calls the passed `function` in its parameter. So, it's totally impossible to handle something in its `for` statement.
At this point I suggest you to use `for` statement and select the index from the array:

```
for (let length = allUsers.length, i = 0, user = allUsers[i]; i < length; i++, user = allUsers[i]) {
    //Here's user that is the same such than the parameter in your function.
}
```

Now you can add a condition link an "until". Let consider the variable `condition`:

```
var condition = false;
for (let length = allUsers.length, i = 0, user = allUsers[i]; i < length && !condition; i++, user = allUsers[i]) {
    //When condition is true, the condition of the for statement gets false and the for cycle stops.
}
```

Or:

```
var condition = false;
for (let length = allUsers.length, i = 0, user = allUsers[i]; i < length; i++, user = allUsers[i]) {
    if (condition)
        break;
    //When condition is true, the above if statement is passed and for cycle is breaked.
}
```

You can also create your own `forEach` function:

```
//In this example I overwrite the normal forEach function
Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback) {
    window.$break = function() {
        window._break = true;
    };
    window.$continue = function() {
        window._continue = true;
    };
    for (let l = this.length, i = 0, e = this[i]; i < l; i++, e = this[i]) {
        if (window._break) {
            window._break = false;
            break;
        }
        if (window._continue) {
            window._continue = false;
            continue;
        }
        callback(e, i);
    }
};
```

Now you have to combine the function `$break()` with the `return` statement in the `function`:

```
var condition = false;
allUsers.forEach(function(user) {
    if (condition) {
        $break();
        return;
    }
});
```

The latter solution I posted, I also written in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbjj0fmc/).

Answer (score 0):

Just use normal **for** (or **some**), foreach just calls passed function on each element there is no way to break.

Answer (score -1):

u can use try - catch  to stop forEach , i write a sample code u can change as u want

```
var q = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
try
    {
        q.forEach(function (x){
            print(x)
            if (x==3)
            throw "bye bye"

        })

    }
catch(e)
    {
        print(e)
    }
```